# gstreamer plugin library not linking against opencv shared object library - “undefined symbol” on CentOS

Tags: opencv, centos, libraries, gstreamer

I have a plugin that uses OpenCV and it works perfectly on Kubuntu. Now I am trying to run the code on CentOS but when I run the pipeline, I get:

```
$ gst-launch videotestsrc ! opencvelement ! ximagesink 
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "opencvelement"
```

When I run ldd in Kubuntu, I get:

```
    $ ldd .libs/libOPENCVELEMENT.so 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0060f000) 
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00a74000) 
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00474000) 
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x006a2000) 
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00110000) 
    libopencv_core.so.2.3 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3 (0x00730000) 
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00209000) 
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x002f4000) 
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00acd000) 
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0031e000) 
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0033c000) 
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00357000) 
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x0035d000) 
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00c9c000) 
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00362000) 
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0036b000) 
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00370000) 
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00e52000) 
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00377000) 
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00a10000)
```

But when I run it on CentOS, I don't see opencv

```
    $ ldd .libs/libOPENCVELEMENT.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7a1fd000) 
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00002ba0ac9b7000) 
    libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstcontroller-0.10.so.0 (0x00002ba0acbc4000) 
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00002ba0acdeb000) 
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00002ba0ad03c000) 
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00002ba0ad326000) 
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00002ba0ad569000) 
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00002ba0ad76c000) 
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002ba0ad970000) 
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00002ba0adb7a000) 
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002ba0adeb7000) 
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00002ba0ae0cb000) 
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002ba0ae3a8000) 
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002ba0ae6a8000) 
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002ba0ae92b000) 
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002ba0aec83000) 
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ba0aee91000) 
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002ba0af0ac000) 
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f6c800000)
```

Here is my makefile.am, which is the same on both OS

```
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libOPENCVELEMENT.la 

# Plugin source files: 
libOPENCVELEMENT_la_SOURCES = opencv_chain.c opencv_chain.h datasetup.h 
libOPENCVELEMENT_la_CFLAGS = \ 
    $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_CFLAGS) \ 
    $(GST_CFLAGS) \ 
    $(OPENCV_CFLAGS) 

libOPENCVELEMENT_la_CXXFLAGS = \ 
    $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_CFLAGS) \ 
    $(GST_CFLAGS) \ 
    $(OPENCV_CFLAGS) 

libOPENCVELEMENT_la_LIBADD = \ 
    $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_LIBS) \ 
    $(GST_LIBS) \ 
    $(OPENCV_LIBS) \ 
    -lopencv_core \ 
    -lopencv_highgui 

libOPENCVELEMENT_la_LDFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGIN_LDFLAGS) 
libOPENCVELEMENT_la_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=disable-static
```

Let me know if you need more information. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When I do a gst-inspect on the .so file I get 


 `$ gst-inspect /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libopencvtest.so    


    (gst-inspect-0.10:5378): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libopencvtest.so': /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libopencvtest.so: undefined symbol:  _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv     

    Could not load plugin file: Opening module failed: /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libopencvtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv`

Comment: I went into /usr/lib64/pkgconfig and modified opencv.pc to explicitly have all libraries. Then I ran a `pkg-config --libs opencv`. When I do an ldd on the plugin, it shows all of the libraries, I but still get `No such element or plugin` when I run gst-inspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by going to /usr/lib64/pkgconfig and modified opencv.pc to explicitly have all libraries. I also had to move the plugins from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10 to /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the opencv development files installed on centos as well. Run a:

```
grep  "OPENVC_" Makefile
```

to check what the Make variables contain. Also you can pipe the linker (undefined symbol) output through c++filt to see the real function name instead of the mangled name.

Comment: `$ grep  "OPENCV_" Makefile
OPENCV_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/opencv
OPENCV_LIBS = -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
        $(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
        $(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
        $(OPENCV_LIBS)
`

Comment: c++filt returns cv::Mat::deallocate()